# Android: Get Numeric input from camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I'd like to give users the ability to use the camera on their phone to enter a numeric value into an edittext.  Such as a check amount, etc.

So the user would hold the phone up to the check or whatever it may be, and the app would use the camera to read in the numeric value and place that text into the edittext.

I'm not sure what to even search for to begin researching this.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Play Service's Vision API, `TextRecognizer` that does OCR which should give you text.

Sample codelab at:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/